# openUrl not being called when I launch the app from Scheme Url

Tags: ios, callback, appdelegate, openurl

This may be a newbie question.

When Application in the background and I click the scheme URL (something like "myApp://blabla") to launch the app, open url methods work fine. No problem.

But when the app doesn't in the background or killed by swiping up, and after that I click the url(myApp://blabla) the app launches but doesn't call the openUrl methods in AppDelegate.

So, I can't navigate the app correctly.

Solved: As @ctietze told, *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* wasn't *return true*, that was the problem.

Comment: According to the docs, "This method is not called if your implementations return false from both the application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods."(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) So check if that's `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to check `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
      /// some
   }
 return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added "myApp" all details under URL types in info.plist file.
You need to add two keys in it. Check image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to comment out the `SceneDelegate` file, delete `ApplicationSceneManifest` in `info.plist`, then restart Xcode. Then the function will be called.